# Excel: Identify a single term in a string and return the result from another table if true

Tags: excel, formulas

I have a list/sheet of single strings (usually 1 to 2 words long):

**List A**

```
fresh 
shoulder bag
acne
paul fisher
```

and another list/sheet of strings:

**List B**

```
Fresh food here
not another shoulder bag
paul fisher is just a person
confidence can come from acne
```

I need some sort of vlookup in order to return **List A** if found in **List B**. EG:

```
Fresh food here               | fresh
not another shoulder bag      | shoulder bag
paul fisher is just a person  | paul fisher
confidence can come from acne | acne
```

I've used a series of formulas but none seem accurate enough.

the last attempted was:

```
=VLOOKUP(IF(ISERROR(LEFT(B10,FIND(",",B10,1))),B10,LEFT(B10,FIND(",",B10,1))),D10:D12,1,TRUE)
```

This does what I want, but only when there is a regular format and the term in List B is followed by a comma.

can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

I used http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/10/09/find-text-with-index-and-match/ as a reference.

I set up my table as such:

```
A              |B                              |C

fresh          |fresh food here                |fresh

shoulder bag   |not another shoulder bag       |shoulder bag

acne           |paul fisher is just a person   |paul fisher

paul fisher    |confidence can come from acne  |acne
```

Cell C1 contains the following formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(B1,"*"&$A$1:$A$4&"*"),0)),"")`. When you enter this in, use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` so it's array-entered. To summarize what the website says, you want to use wildcards (`*`) to your advantage. The `COUNTIF()` function determines which key the string contains. The `MATCH()` function gets the position in the string where the key occurs. The `INDEX()` function gets the key that `MATCH()` has found. `IFERROR()` is obviously just for error checking.